Metrizability of point-open topology
For arbitrary topological spaces $(X,\mathcal{T}_X)$ and $(Y,\mathcal{T}_Y)$, let $Y^X$ denote the space of mappings from $X$ to $Y$ endowed with the topology of point-wise convergence $\mathcal{T}_p$, i.e. such that a sequence in $Y^X$ converges if and only if the image of every $x\in X$ under the sequence defines a converging sequence in $(Y,\mathcal{T}_Y)$.
What conditions need to be imposed on $X$ in order for $(Y^X,\mathcal{T}_p)$ to be metrizable? It is hinted that the cardinality of $X$ should provide a sufficient condition. To be completely honest, I'm not even convinced that for arbitrary $Y$ the space $(Y^X,\mathcal{T}_p)$ is metrizable, since there are no conditions imposed on $Y$ at all (I could imagine just taking a huge space, such that $(Y^X,\mathcal{T}_p)$ is no longer first-countable, but haven't been able to cook up a counter-example of that sort). A hint would be much appreciated.

Hint: the point wise topology on $Y^X$ is simply the product topology $Y^X=\prod_{x\in X} Y$.

@GiorgioGenovesi Thanks for the hint, but I don't see how this condition gives any kind of notion of metrizability, especially considering that I'm looking for a sufficient condition, and not a way to rule out spaces.

Sorry, I should have specified, the hint was just for a sufficient condition. For the full metrizability conditions you have that $Y$ embeds into $Y^X$ with the product topology. So in particular $Y$ must be metric. The topology on $X$ doesn't matter since pointwise convergence doesn't make use of the topology of $X$.

Hint for conditions on $Y$: $Y$ embeds in $Y^X$, and metrizability is hereditary.
Hint for conditions on $X$: consider the cardinality of $X$. Note $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb R}$ is not metrizable.

Thank you very much for your answer, I believe I have the proof now. Just to be clear, though, it is absolutely necessary that $Y$ be a metric space, right? We can't have $X$ and $Y$ be arbitrary topological spaces and then only put constraints on $X$ to get a sufficient condition for $Y^X$ to be metrizable with the point-open topology, correct?

Correct: if $Y^X$ is metrizable then so is $Y$.
